# Return result 4 through 8 in SharePoint search query

Tags: search-results, content-search-web-part

I have a request to have two Content Search web parts on a page. The first returns results 1 through 3, the second returns 4 through 8. They both pull from the same announcement list. As I am new to trying to build queries, I'm not sure how to achieve this. At this time, my query looks like this:

```
path:{Site.URL} ContentTypeId:0x010400E4C69AC8BC35174BA8C09869EEB5F949*
```

This, of course, works. I just need to bring back records 4 through 8.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your sort criteria?

Comment: LastModifiedTime Descending

Comment: Odd request, is this so you can do some sort of visual stacking? If so, you can achieve this in the Display and Control Templates.

Comment: Odd, request? Perhaps. If you visualize it like this: There is a slider CSWP that pulls the first 3 results. Below the slider is another CSWP named Other News. This "Other News" would display the next 5 results. All of these are pulling from the Announcements Content Type. I don't want to bake in this logic into the Display Template as it is only needed on the front page of the site. The "Other News" will be used elsewhere, but in those cases I want it to pull back results 1 through 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the web part settings! Just change the 1 into a 4... done!

[image: web part settings]